What is the idiomatic way to build hierarchical const &str values?
I would like to define a const &str that uses the value of another const &str. What is the standard way to do this in Rust?
const FOO: &str = "foo";
const FOOBAR: &str = FOO + "bar"; // "foobar"

fn main() {
    println!("{}{}", "fee", FOOBAR); // "feefoobar"
}


With a dependency, const_format is just few lines of code away:
const FOOBAR: &str = const_format::concatcp!(FOO, "bar"); // "foobar"

Without dependency this is a bit longer:
macro_rules! concat_const_str {
    ($a:expr, $b:expr $(,)?) => {{
        const __CONCAT_A: &str = $a;
        const __CONCAT_B: &str = $b;
        const __CONCAT_LEN: usize = __CONCAT_A.len() + __CONCAT_B.len();
        const __CONCAT_STORAGE: [u8; __CONCAT_LEN] = {
            let mut storage = [0; __CONCAT_LEN];
            let a = __CONCAT_A.as_bytes();
            let mut i = 0;
            while i < a.len() {
                storage[i] = a[i];
                i += 1;
            }
            let b = __CONCAT_B.as_bytes();
            let mut j = 0;
            while j < b.len() {
                storage[i] = b[j];
                j += 1;
                i += 1;
            }
            storage
        };
        match ::std::str::from_utf8(&__CONCAT_STORAGE) {
            Ok(s) => s,
            Err(_) => unreachable!(),
        }
    }};
}

const FOO: &str = "foo";
const FOOBAR: &str = concat_const_str!(FOO, "bar"); // "foobar"


I'm new to Rust, but seems to me like there should be a better way. Is there some other method maybe not using const str to avoid using lots of string literals?

@gogators Why do you think there should be a better way? This is perfect - it can be nicely encapsulated in a reusable macro (as const_format) did. Also why do you think this create many string literals?

E.g. in Java, I could assign a string literal to final static String BASE_URL, and then create many other final static urls based on BASE_URL.  In vanilla Rust (without the const_format dep) I would not be able to reuse BASE_URL.

@gogators Well I provided a macro to do that without deps. And FWIW, final in Java will calculate the string at runtime, so equivalent to LazyLock.
